# How to integrate js leaflet with Backbone js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, openstreetmap, leaflet

I am trying to develop an application that is based on Backbone JS. I want to embed a OpenStreetMap map based on  leaflet JS but I could not find any tutorial.

Comment: could you provide more details about what the application is that you're trying to develop? It may not be necessary to have to add backbone into it, though perhaps you would if you had a lot of data going back from the client to the server and back again. Extra details would help.

Comment: @RoybertSoylend For now I just want to know how to integrate in a leaflet for Backbone JS.
My problem is how to retrieve the div from the html template in the view Backbone js.I use in the javascript:

var mc= $ ('# map', $ (this.el));
var map = L.map(mc).setView ([51,505, -0.09], 13);{
maxZoom: 18,
attribution: "Map data OpenStreetMap ontributors,CloudMade Imagery '
}).addTo (map);

and the error  displayed in the console:
Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property 'length' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Can not read property '_leaflet' of nu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a jsfiddle to show how you can use Leaflet inside a Backbone.View:
http://jsfiddle.net/theotheo/CJcK6/

```
// bare template
<script type='template' id='map-template'>
   <div id="map"></div>
</script>

// simple view
var MapView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template($('#map-template').html()),
  render: function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template());

    var map = L.map(this.$('#map')[0]).setView([55.75, 37.58], 10);
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/4e5f745e28654b7eb26aab577eed79ee/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>[…]',
      maxZoom: 18
    }).addTo(map);

    return this;
  }
});
```

Feel free to ask.

**Update**:

Example with jQuery Mobile: http://jsfiddle.net/theotheo/mh6mA/

Comment: Thanks a lot.But i have another question:My template is based on jquery mobile.So how i can integrate this solution in my application based on jquery mobile, leaflet js and backbone js.

Comment: You're welcome! Sooo... «jQuery Mobile» you said. I've updated my answer and added jsfiddle for this case. But what are the issues you encountered? For me it just works.

Comment: My problem that with jquery mobile the map does not take the whole container div and when I move it,the map bug that never appears.But finaly i find the solution:

Comment: `setTimeout(function() {
   var map, minimal, motorways;
   var pointLayer = new L.LayerGroup();
   var cloudmadeAttribution = '',
   cloudmadeOptions = {maxZoom: 18, attribution: cloudmadeAttribution},
   cloudmadeUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/8ee2a50541944fb9bcedded5165f09d9/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
 
   map = new L.Map(this.$('#map')[0], {center: new L.LatLng(36.914764,10.085449), zoom: 6, layers: [minimal, motorways, pointLayer]});
}, 400);`

Comment: setTimeout(func, 400)? Hmm, I think, there can be a race condition. Keep in mind ;).

Comment: I find this solution in this code https://github.com/tegansnyder/OpenStreetMaps-Leaflet-JQuery-Mobile-Examples
So i combined your solution with this code to get the correct function.
P.S: My application is a phonegap mobile application

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the link. I've just thought you used '''setTimeout''' for another purpose. Now I think, that's ok.

Comment: @user1248256 When I view your jsFiddle example the map renders incorrectly - the tiles are cut off and you have to pan left to see them. The "setTimeout" example just waits until the view is rendered to the page, which isn't an elegant solution. Were you ever able to resolve this rendering issue?

Comment: @AlexBain, I have no idea what the problem is with the map rendering. Unfortunately, jsFiddle «is under maintenance» right now. So I will try to answer your question later. But what browser do you use?

Comment: @user1248256 I'm using the latest version of Chrome. I added an answer underneath this comment that renders the map correctly, for me. Take a look.

Answer (score 8):

I found the above answer to render the map incorrectly.

Leaflet expects the containing element to already be located in the DOM when a map is initialized. This is why using `setTimeout` "works". By the time `setTimeout` fires the View has been appended to the page, so Leaflet can initialize correctly.

I believe it is cleaner to break apart the append step and the render step. By appending the View to the page before rendering it you can ensure that Leaflet will properly initialize without having to use `setTimeout`.

Here is an example, based on the one above:

```
var MapView = Backbone.View.extend({

  render: function () {
    this.map = L.map(this.el).setView([55.75, 37.58], 10);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/4e5f745e28654b7eb26aab577eed79ee/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>[…]',
      maxZoom: 18
    }).addTo(map);

    return this;
  }

});

$('body').append(MapView.el);
MapView.render();
```